# React.js with MVC ASP.NET TTFB loading of .jsx takes too long

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have integrated `React.js` with my `asp.net MVC` application. The main thing is it loads fast enough when I am debugging locally or when I am entering the website consecutively, which is I assume due to caching.

**But**

when I am entering my website for the first time after like let's say, half an hour the `.jsx` file takes a crazy long time

The time and the values:
[image: You can see the time and the values here]

It took 32 s! I hope that's not normal and it's not that big of a file either. It's only `17.6 KB`.

Now I am pretty new to `React.js`, I am wondering what I have done wrong or could this be happening due to a slow server, I don't have the best server at my disposal but other websites on this server are nowhere near this slow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can preload scripts in MVC projects. Right inside App_Start > ReactConfig.cs and add the following line inside Configure():

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration = new ReactSiteConfiguration().AddScript("~/Scripts/gapi.js").AddScript("~/Scripts/firebase.js").AddScript("~/Scripts/React/Home.jsx");
```

As you can see I am using gapi and firebase scripts which were also required in my Home.jsx, but the problem is I cannot reach the functions inside these scripts from Home.jsx so this all started to slowly drive me insane.

What I did as a solution was simply give up trying to use Reactjs inside asp.net MVC and made a separate proper reactjs application and I am using C# as a web service. Now I am having no loading time problems, it loads like lightning.

Comment: what led you to this solution?  We are troubleshooting a similar situation.

Comment: Hi @foldinglettuce I'm sorry you have to deal with .net MVC and react together. I was simply trying to find a work-around. Even this solution didn't satisfy me that much, I eventually switched to WEB Api